# JavaScript, Maps API: Click one of many elements, extract a portion of its name, and apply it in a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Forgive me if I misuse any technical terms; I'm still fairly new to programming. I'm creating a map with Google Maps API 3.12 that will include a menu of 600 entries with addresses, but this is mostly a JavaScript issue. Each address is clickable (in a menu) that will cause the map to go to its respective marker. Alternately, clicking a marker will send users to that place in the menu.

I started just going through and writing each out, but I've quickly realize this will send my code well over 20,000 lines, which will both slow my code and be torturous for me.

Here is some of the initial code:

```
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.88267,-87.623758); //etc for all 600 addresses
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng1,
    map: map
    }); //etc for all 600 markers
var contentString1 = '<div>blahblahblah</div>'; //gives content specific to place1.
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
```

The following is where I'd like to save on lines. Instead of copying and pasting this entire code 600 times for `place`/`marker`/`contentString1` and `2` and `3`, up to `600`, I'm trying to figure out a way to write this function once for all of them:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("place1"), "click", function() {
    map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(15);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString1);
    infowindow.open(map, marker1);
    window.location = '#map-canvas';
});
```

This code makes it so I can click on the menu, and the map will jump to the corresponding marker and also pop up an info window. It is always just, "click `placeX`, go to `markerX` at `latlngX` with the respective `infowindow` content," but I am having the hardest time figuring something out that will be universal.

Could something like the following work? My theory is that clicking on any `place` in the menu could trigger this function rather than having to click on a specific `place`. This will then pull out the appending number of the specific `place` that is clicked (I call that number `x` below), and apply it to the function below. If I changed the `place` elements from IDs to class elements, would this make it possible? I'm not even sure how to do it then. Would that in turn create a different problem with the code I already have?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("place"), "click", function (x) {
    map.setCenter("marker" + x.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(15);
    infowindow.setContent("contentString" + x);
    infowindow.open(map, "marker" + x);
    window.location = '#map-canvas';
});
```

I've been trying variations on this for days now, but I can't get anything to work. I'm not sure if it's issues of theory, scope, syntax or all of the above. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: if all you technically want to do is plot the 600 addresses, and if you know the lat/long for them already, I would just stick it into a database, use ajax to retrieve addresses from the database and plot it automatically.

Comment: I plot them, but also give the ability to click the menu to go to the point on the map and vice versa (I didn't include that code, but it would use the same theory needed here). I've never touched Ajax, but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: if it's in a database it would be the same thing. both the menu and the map can be populated at once.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Do you happen to have a link to a guide for what you have in mind? I don't quite understand how that would account for the clicking actions to or from the map's markers.

Comment: it would be something like this: 1. you would use ajax to retrieve addresses from database. 2. the addresses are usually in JSON format, which can easily be converted to a javascript object or array. 3. now you just need to iterate through the addresses, plot it on the map, put in the menu, add any event handlers, etc. or any other functions you want on each of them, and that's it.

Comment: to get started right away, I would use PHP/MySQL for the database and server side of things, then use jQuery for your ajax calls, event handlers, etc.